# Getting number of bytes from BytesIO

Tags: python, io, bytesio

I want to get the exact number of bytes from a BytesIO object, the same bytes that read() returns.

The closest way to do it I found is:

```
readable = io.BytesIO(b'\xff\xd8')
print(sys.getsizeof(readable))
```

However, instead of 2 got 48 as a result.

Comment: Do you mean `len(readable.read())`?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` doesn’t get the length of an iterable. It gets the size of the Python object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io.BytesIO` is a stream. Consume it to get the content's size:

```py
>>> sys.getsizeof(io.BytesIO(b'\xff\xd8').getvalue())
35
```

and use `len()` instead of `sys.getsizeof` if you want to get its length:

```py
>>> len(io.BytesIO(b'\xff\xd8').getvalue())
2
```

or read a specific number of bytes manually, so you'll know the size beforehand:

```py
>>> io.BytesIO(b'\xff\xd8').read(2)
b'\xff\xd8'
>>> sys.getsizeof(io.BytesIO(b'\xff\xd8').read(2))
35
>>> len(io.BytesIO(b'\xff\xd8').read(2))
2
```

Since this is a stream, size can't be known before consuming the stream.

The reason you don't get `2` with your code is because you're asking the size of the `BytesIO` instance instead of the length of the stream's value:

```py
>>> readable = io.BytesIO(b'\xff\xd8')
>>> readable
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000024A8CFC3BD0>
>>> sys.getsizeof(readable)
115
>>> len(readable.getvalue())
2
```